# Ternary operators in C#

Tags: c#, .net, methods, ternary-operator

With the ternary operator, it is possible to do something like the following (assuming Func1() and Func2() return an int:

```
int x = (x == y) ? Func1() : Func2();
```

However, is there any way to do the same thing, without returning a value?  For example, something like (assuming Func1() and Func2() return void):

```
(x == y) ? Func1() : Func2();
```

I realise this could be accomplished using an if statement, I just wondered if there was a way to do it like this.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but the proper name is the conditional operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691313(VS.71).aspx

Comment: @Brian: In that same article, "It is at times also called the ternary operator".  So really, both are used.

Comment: @Nelson - in the fashion that the sum sign can also be called a binary operator, and that the incrementation operator can also be called unary operator? Yes... but it's still not a correct way to name it, despite usually being the only known ternary operator. (Are there more? Good question.)

Comment: Yes, ternary (and related ones such as unary, binary) are more generalized names.  So the conditional operator is a ternary operator (or "the" ternary operator if the language syntax doesn't provide another), but a ternary operator is not necessarily a conditional operator.  I think in the context of programming languages, both will usually be understood to mean the same thing.  Unless there are more, like you said.

Comment: Searching Google for 'C# "ternary operator"' and 'C# "conditional operator"' returned a similar number of results, so it appears they are both used with roughly the same frequency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Weird, but you could do

```
class Program
{
    private delegate void F();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ((1 == 1) ? new F(f1) : new F(f2))();
    }

    static void f1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }

    static void f2()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of extra work to avoid just using "if" and "else". Nice snippet though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. As far as I remember, the ternary operator is used in an **expression context** and not as a statement. The *compiler needs to know the type for the expression* and `void` is not really a type.

You could try to define a function for this:

```
void iif(bool condition, Action a, Action b)
{
    if (condition) a(); else b();
}
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
iif(x > y, Func1, Func2);
```

But this does not really make your code any clearer...

Answer (score 1):

If you feel confident, you'd create a static method whose only purpose is to absorb the expression and "make it" a statement.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void Do(this Object x) { }
}
```

In this way you could call the ternary operator and invoke the extension method on it.

```
((x == y) ? Func1() : Func2()).Do();
```

Or, in an almost equivalent way, writing a static method (if the class when you want to use this "shortcut" is limited).

```
private static void Do(object item){ }
```

... and calling it in this way

```
Do((x == y) ? Func1() : Func2());
```

However I strongly reccomend to not use this "shortcut" for same reasons already made explicit by the authors before me.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the ternary operator is an expression, whereas actions/void functions are statements. You could make them return `object`, but I think that an if/else block would make the intent much clearer (i.e. the actions are being executed for their side-effects instead of their values).