# Ternary operator failing when using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

This works:

```
int valueAsInt = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(value, out valueAsInt))
{
    record.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(record, valueAsInt, null);
}
else
{
    record.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(record, value, null);
}
```

This, however, does not. Unsure why.

```
Int32.TryParse(value, out valueAsInt) ? record.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(record, valueAsInt, null) :record.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(record, value, null);
```

I receive the following error messages:

Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Error 2 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'void' and 'void'

I was just curious as to why the ternary operator fails in this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ternary operators in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765360/ternary-operators-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection is red herring here. In C#, not all expressions are valid as independent statements. For instance:

```
a + b;
```

will not compile.

Similarly, `? :` is not a valid *expression-statement* construct according to C# grammar. You always have to do something with the value of the ternary expression. If you don't care about the value, you should go with an `if` statement.

> #### [Relevant Portion of C# Grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(v=VS.71).aspx):
>
> *expression-statement*:
>
> > *statement-expression*   ;
>
> *statement-expression*:
>
> > *invocation-expression*
> > *object-creation-expression*
> > *assignment*
> > *post-increment-expression*
> > *post-decrement-expression*
> > *pre-increment-expression*
> > *pre-decrement-expression*

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator expects to return a value. The methods you are calling, I would guess, do not. :)

From the [MSDN remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> The condition must evaluate to true or
>   false. If condition is true,
>   first_expression is evaluated and
>   becomes the result. If condition is
>   false, second_expression is evaluated
>   and becomes the result. Only one of
>   the two expressions is evaluated.
>
> Either the type of first_expression
>   and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must
>   exist from one type to the other.

If there are no types involved in the execution of your statements (other than `void`), the ternary operator won't work in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not returning anything from the clause. Ternary operators are used specifically as if/else when the resulting value is to be assigned to some variable or returned.