# Is there a ternary operator to run a function in c#?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

In `C#` I know you can do things like this:

```
int number = true ? 1 : 0;
```

This returns the left or right side depending on if the `Boolean` is true or not.

But is there a way to do the same thing but instead run a function instead of returning a value? Something like this:

This doesn't work (I get multiple syntax errors)

```
WPS.EDIT_MODE ? ExecuteEditMode() : ExecutePublicMode();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't that work?  If both functions return an int I'd expect it to.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765360/ternary-operators-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conditional operator *must* return a value.  Assuming the functions don't both return a meaningful value for you, you should use an `if` statement to do that:

```
if(someCondition)
    doA();
else
    doB();
```

Although technically you could use an anonymous function to do this if you *really* wanted:

```
int number = someCondition ?
    new Func<int>(() => { doA(); return 0; })() :
    new Func<int>(() => { doB(); return 1; })();
```

but that's not suggested; using an `if/else` is both easier and more readable for that case.

Comment: I updated my question. So I guess the if else is the best way if the functions don't return anything. What if they return something, but u dont assign it to a variable?

Comment: @omega I assumed the functions were void returning from the start; your edit didn't change the validity of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If both functions return an `int`, yes.

The ternary operator is about returning values. Not returning values doesn't make sense.

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on
>   the value of a Boolean expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: He specifically said *instead of returning a value*, which would imply that they don't.