# How to call function which has action by using ternary operator?

Tags: c#, lambda, ternary

I defined the function

```
public void HogeFunc(Action<Bar> act)
{
    this.act = act;
}
```

If I call HogeFunc, it works.

```
if(isFuga)
{
    hogeClass.HogeFunc(null);
}
else
{
    hogeClass.HogeFunc(this.MyFunc);
}
```

But, I'd like to call HogeFunc by using ternary operator.

So, I wrote like below

**try1**

```
hogeClass.HogeFunc(isFuga ? null : this.MyFunc);
```

**try2**

```
hogeClass.HogeFunc((i)=>{return isFuga ? null : this.MyFunc;});
```

But, there didn't work...

Could you tell me how to?

Comment: Please provide exact error. Looked like duplicate of one of many how to use "ternary with action" (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765360/ternary-operators-in-c-sharp) but probably not.

Comment: `HogeFunc` takes an `Action<Bar>` and actions don't return values, but you appear to be trying to use to return a value.

Answer (score 1):

ternary operators need to return the same type from both options.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use ternary operators in C#, both results MUST return the same object type.

Try casting `null` to the same return type of `this.MyFunc`

Answer (score 1):

Your first try looks correct to me, however you can also call like:

```
isFuga ? hogeClass.HogeFunc(null) : hogeClass.HogeFunc(this.MyFunc);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying
But, I don't want to write "hogeClass.HogeFunc" twice.

Comment: @shinriyo: But does it work or not? Because your first try is correct and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, you are just mixing parts of the ternary operation and you need type cast.

Following code:

```
if(isFuga)
{
    hogeClass.HogeFunc(null);
}
else
{
    hogeClass.HogeFunc(this.MyFunc);
}
```

can be rwritten as here:

```
hogeClass.HogeFunc(isFuge ? (Action<Bar>)null : (Action<Bar>)this.MyFunc);
```

or here:

```
hogeClass.HogeFunc(isFuge ? (Action<Bar>)null : (Action<Bar>)(x_bar => 
{
   this.MyFunc(x_bar);
}));
```